# Spring Security Facebook Authentication doesn't work - Internal Server error

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security Facebook plugin in my grails app. It shows the below error messege when returning from facebook page after authentication. The facebook user details are not saved in database. Kindly help to solve this error and to authenticate facebook users successfully. Thanks in advance.

FacebookUser.groovy Domain Class

```
class FacebookUser {

    long uid
  String accessToken
  Date accessTokenExpires

    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    static constraints = {
        uid unique: true
    }
}
```

Config.groovy settings for spring-security-facebook app

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='com.awnsys.gcx.FacebookUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.appUserConnectionPropertyName = 'user'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.appId='APPID'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.secret='secretID'

grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.autoCreate.enabled=true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.autoCreate.roles=['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_FACEBOOK',]
```

Below is the error Message shown in browser when redirects from facebook after the user accepts app in facebook

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI : /myapp/j_spring_security_facebook_check
Class : grails.validation.ValidationException
Message : Validation Error(s) occurred during save(): - Field error in object 'com.mydomain.myapp.User' on field 'username': rejected value [facebook_100005487962357]; codes [com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.error.com.mydomain.myapp.User.username,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.error.username,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.error.java.lang.String,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.error,user.username.email.error.com.mydomain.myapp.User.username,user.username.email.error.username,user.username.email.error.java.lang.String,user.username.email.error,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.invalid.com.mydomain.myapp.User.username,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.invalid.username,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.invalid.java.lang.String,com.mydomain.myapp.User.username.email.invalid,user.username.email.invalid.com.mydomain.myapp.User.username,user.username.email.invalid.username,user.username.email.invalid.java.lang.String,user.username.email.invalid,email.invalid.com.mydomain.myapp.User.username,email.invalid.username,email.invalid.java.lang.String,email.invalid]; arguments [username,class com.mydomain.myapp.User,facebook_100005487962357]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] is not a valid e-mail address]
```

Around line 149 of DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy

```
146:                    appUser.setProperty(securityConf.userLookup.passwordExpiredPropertyName, false)
147:                }
148:                AppUserDomainClazz.withTransaction {
149:                    appUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
150:                }
151:            }
152:            user[appUserConnectionPropertyName] = appUser
```

Around line 148 of DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy

```
145:                    appUser.setProperty(securityConf.userLookup.accountLockedPropertyName, false)
146:                    appUser.setProperty(securityConf.userLookup.passwordExpiredPropertyName, false)
147:                }
148:                AppUserDomainClazz.withTransaction {
149:                    appUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
150:                }
151:            }
```

Around line 67 of FacebookAuthProvider.groovy

```
64:                    log.error("Can't create user w/o access_token")
65:                    throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Can't receive access_token from Facebook")
66:                }
67:                user = facebookAuthDao.create(token)
68:                justCreated = true
69:            } else {
70:                log.error "User $token.uid doesn't exist, and creation of a new user is disabled."
```

Around line 67 of FacebookAuthProvider.groovy

```
64:                    log.error("Can't create user w/o access_token")
65:                    throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Can't receive access_token from Facebook")
66:                }
67:                user = facebookAuthDao.create(token)
68:                justCreated = true69:            } else {
70:                log.error "User $token.uid doesn't exist, and creation of a new user is disabled."
```

Trace

```
Line | Method
->>  149 | doCall                in DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    687 | withTransaction       in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
|    148 | create . . . . . . .  in DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy
|     67 | authenticate          in FacebookAuthProvider.groovy
|     40 | attemptAuthentication in FacebookAuthRedirectFilter.groovy
|   1145 | runWorker             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run                   in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default plugin generates username like `facebook_%UID%` (`facebook_100005487962357` from your stacktrace). Seems that your `User` domain requires an email for `.username` field (and have such constraint), so it cannot be saved.

At this case I suggest you to implement own logic for filling User object, by implementing `FacebookAuthService.createAppUser` method. See docs: http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/5%20Customization.html#5.1%20Using%20FacebookAuthService

And also, Facebook Authentication plugin don't know user email (it's not provided by Facebook Login by default), you have to fetch it from Facebook API, see example: https://github.com/splix/grails-facebook-authentication-example/blob/master/grails-app/services/FacebookAuthService.groovy#L51

Comment: Thank you Igor. Yes i set email: true for username files in constraint. When i removed that It successfully authenticate facebook user and stored `facebook_100005487962357` in database. but what i need is to get facebook used email id and store in DB. implementing `FacebookAuthService` showing error as importing class `Facebook`, `FacebookTemplate`. for that i tried spring-social-core and spring-social-facebook plugin. but it showing exception after installing tat plugin. and my app didn't work. plz help me to get the email id of facebook user. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at example app, and just make exactly configuration

Comment: For Facebook and FacebookProfile classes i installed `spring social facebook` plugin. after the plugin was installed its showing this error

Comment: StackTrace below(in multiple comments) total 5 errors:

`C:\Users\Administrator\.grails\2.2.3\projects\myapp\plugins\spring-social-facebook-0.1.32\src\groovy\grails\plugins\springsocial\config\facebook\FacebookConfig.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class javax.inject.Inject
 @ line 18, column 1.
 import javax.inject.Inject`

Comment: COREPATH = C:\Users\Administrator\.grails\2.2.3\projects\myapp\plugins\spring-social-core-0.1.31\src\groovy\grails\plugins\springsocial

`COREPATH\SpringSocialProviderSignInController.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInAttempt
 @ line 21, column 1.
 import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInAttempt`

Comment: `COREPATH\config\core\SpringSocialCoreConfig.groovy: 17: unable to resolve class javax.inject.Inject
 @ line 17, column 1.
 import javax.inject.Inject
   ^


COREPATH\connect\web\GrailsConnectSupport.groovy: 21: unable to resolve class org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectSupport
 @ line 21, column 1.
 import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectSupport
   ^`

Comment: `COREPATH\signin\SpringSocialSimpleSignInAdapter.groovy: 23: unable to resolve class org.springframework.social.connect.web.SignInAdapter
 @ line 23, column 1.
 import org.springframework.social.connect.web.SignInAdapter
   ^
5 errors`

Comment: Above 4 comments are the stacktrace i got while running the app after installin the `spring-social-facebook` plugin. How to resolve this error?

Comment: As I see, it's unrelated to Spring Security Facebook plugin, it's all about Spring Social plugin dependencies, sorry I can't help you there. Btw, it seems that you forgot to add some dependencies

Comment: ok anyway thanks for your response. will check with the example app you given and if i sort out the issue. I will post here.

Comment: I forgot to add 

` dependencies {
        
compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.0.1.RELEASE'
}`

in `BuildConfig.groovy` thats y it was showing error. Now the app works and get the facebook user email, name etc as you gave in the example link. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are implementing FacebookAuthService and having problems with Facebook and FacebookProfile classes being marked with error, make sure you added to your BuildConfig.groovy file the two plugins

```
compile ":spring-social-core:0.1.31"
compile ":spring-social-facebook:0.1.32"
```

NOTE: Spring Social Facebook is not the same plugin as Spring Security Facebook.
So if you have the lines above, you will still have to compile the Spring Social plugins.

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
compile ':spring-security-facebook:0.15.2-CORE2'
```